# How to update multiple tables from excel file in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, excel

Hi I am new to SQL server.
I need help to update two tables from excel file.
Excel file includes all the data in 1 sheet and that data need to update on SQL server tables.

example data on the Excel file 
Employeename, Deparment

SQL tables are
employer details and departments

I know how to add to the table but I want to know for the multiple tables

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps,

1. Create a temporary table with the same structure as excel.
2. Import data from excel to temp. table using SSIS
   package/Export/Import Wizard/ Just Copy & Paste
3. Insert into department table by selecting distinct departments from
   temp. table.
4. Insert into employee table by selecting employee details, department
   pk can be selected from department table by department name.
5. Remove temporary table.

Comment: Is it possible to use integration services to export data directly to tables ?

Comment: yes, you can do entire task by using a single package.

Answer (score 0):

Create and use a SSIS package to do your task. You can alternatively use Sql Server Export/Import Wizard .

Comment: thank you for reply, can I know how to create two tables.